# Null test in bash

Tags: bash

This returns `null`:

`jq --arg light "$i" '.lightstates[$light].on' "$tmp_dir/evening_brightness.json"`

However, when I test for null, I get an unexpected result:

```
[[ -z $(jq --arg light "$i" '.lightstates[$light].on' "$tmp_dir/evening_brightness.json") ]] && echo "null" || echo "not null"
not null
```

I have tried variations - using -n and testing for an empty string - but neither of these gives the result I want over a range of value (where I want to not echo anything where there's no useful value in a variable).

(Potential values are: true, false, string, null.)

Comment: `jq` is printing the literal string `null`, not a special value.

Comment: true, false, string and null are all strings with non-zero length. Thus your test succeeds for each of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jq` is outputting the literal string `null`.  However, you can add the `-e` flag to `json` so that its exit status is non-zero when it produces a null or false value.

```
if jq -e --arg light "$i" '.lightstates[$light].on' "$tmp_dir/evening_brightness.json" > /dev/null; then
  echo "not null"
else
  echo "null"
fi
```

Comment: Thank you. The flag -e flag is useful - I hadn't thought to look for a jq option.

Answer (score 2):

bash does not know a `null` value. You need to compare strings in this case:

```
[ "$(jq -c '.abc' <<< "{}")" == "null" ] && echo "is null"
```

alternatively you can use the `--exit-status` option from `jq`:

> -e / --exit-status:
>
> Sets  the exit status of jq to 0 if the last output values was neither false nor null, 1 if the last output value was either > false or null, or 4 if no valid result was ever produced. Normally jq exits with 2 if there was any usage problem or system error, 3 if there was a jq program compile error, or 0 if the jq
>   program ran.

Comment: Thanks. Is it really the case that bash doesn't know about null? Isn't it more accurate to say that I am testing for null or an empty string, but that jq is outputting a string (which is not empty)?

Comment: both statements are correct, but the reason for your error is indeed more accurately described by your second sentence.